# Yii Framework - CGridView sort related columns

Tags: php, gridview, frameworks, jquery-ui-sortable, yii

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help. I've been searching for an answer, but haven't found one yet. I've run into "solutions" that haven't worked that run from 1 line, to re-writing an entire class.

I've got the "grid" to show the relation, and am able to use the search feature. What I can't figure out is the sort feature. The column header becomes non-clickable once the below changes have been made.

This is what I have:

The relation name/label is "company," setup in Employee model.

Table: Employee -- Column: idCompany
&
Table: Company -- Column: companyNick

admin.php - VIEW

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'employee-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
            array(
                    'name'=>'company',   
                    'value'=>'$data->company->companyNick',
            ),
            'lastName',
            'firstName',

ETC...
```

Employee.php - MODEL

```
public function search()
    {
            // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
            // should not be searched.

            $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

            //Company Relation Search
            $criteria->compare('company.companyNick',$this->company,true);  
            $criteria->with='company'; 

            //stock
            $criteria->compare('idEmployee',$this->idEmployee,true);
            $criteria->compare('idAccount',$this->idAccount,true);

ETC...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been having the same problems and in the end solved it this way:

Model Search method:

```
$sort = new CSort();
$sort->attributes = array(
'assignedTo'=>array(
    'asc'=>'(SELECT surname from people 
            WHERE people.person_id = t.assigned_to) ASC',       
    'desc'=>'(SELECT surname from people 
            WHERE people.person_id = t.assigned_to) DESC',     
    ),
    '*', // add all of the other columns as sortable   
);
```

View file:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'tasks-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
//'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'task',
    array(
    'header'=>'Assigned To',
    'value'=> '$data->assignedTo->surname.", ".$data->assignedTo->forename',
        'name'=> 'assignedTo',
        'sortable'=>TRUE,
        ),
    'due_date',
    'status',       
),
```

));

This way I'm selecting a single field from the related table into the order by clause and then ordering by that, you create the table join in the expression, in this case it is -`people.person_id = t.assigned_to` (where t is a table alias provided by yii). This is perhaps not the most efficient way to create the order by clause but it works!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a daily question on [yii].  Strip that stuff out of your search function, and add a filter attribute to your CGridView column like so:

```
        array(
                'name'=>'company',   
                'value'=>'$data->company->companyNick',
                'filter' => CHtml::listData(Company::model()->findAll(),'id','nick'),
        ),
```

Comment: I don't want to create a drop down menu.  I want to sort (not select) using the table header; as with the others.

Comment: You still can.  However, if you want to sort by the company name rather than the foreign key, you'll have to hack it in to your dataprovider (e.g. $model->search())

Comment: I'm starting on the right path with CSort... you're not being very specific.  Thanks for telling me that I need to change "something" to make it work.  Obviously.

Comment: Wow, I'm sure you'll get a lot of mileage out of the whole "I'm an intolerable, ungrateful jerk to everyone who attempts to help me" shtick.

Comment: Well, thanks.  Try reading the question next time, rather than replying with a nondescript answer to which is not related.

Answer (score 2):

There is also good explanation how to do this on Yii web site Wiki page:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/

Answer (score 1):

I like Mike H's answer. I also want to point out that you could, instead of entering the raw SQL, use with() to perform a relational query and then set select to false to prevent actually loading the related models. You can also use the related attribute's attributeLabel in the view by passing the dot-notated string, e.g.,:

```
// Controller
$gridDataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('EmrFormPatientTie', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'condition'=>'flag_locked=0',
        'with'=>array('patient'=>array(
            'select'=>false, // Perform relational query without loading related models
        )),
    ),
    'pagination'=>(array('pageSize'=>15)),
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
            'patient.display_id'=>array(
                'asc'=>'patient.display_id',
                'desc'=>'patient.display_id DESC',
            ),
            '*', // Make all other columns sortable, too
        ),
    ),
));

// View
array(
    'name'=>'patient.display_id',
    'value'=>'$data->patient->display_id',
),
```